# How to remover word CHAPTER at the beginning of the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

How can I remove the word CHAPTER at the beginning of the table of contents and keep it before each of chapter name as in this figure

[image]

Comment: Please post a full minimal working example. Post code, not a picture of the code so that we can try compiling your code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Just for reference: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Hard to say without a MWE, but it seems that `tocchapterhead` is an option of your document class that controls this behavior. At a first glance, try to put in the options: 
`\documentclass[tocchapterhead=false]{name-of-the-class}` among the others that you may already have.

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroCuttin  Alessandro Cuttin 
This command works
\documentclass[tocchapterhead=false]{name-of-the-class}

Comment: let me turn that into an answer. please, for future reference, edit your question by stating at least which documentclass you are using

Comment: For the sake of search engines, this looks like `ccw_chithesis` class. Can you confirm that?

Comment: This is the document class that I used:

   \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
   \ProvidesClass{UPMthesis}[2008/07/12 UPM Thesis Class for LaTex2e]

    \RequirePackage{setspace}[1998/04/8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without a MWE, but it seems from the screenshot you posted that `tocchapterhead` is an option of your document class that controls this behavior.

At a first glance, try to put  `tocchapterhead=false` among the other options that you may already have, like so:

```
\documentclass[tocchapterhead=false]{name-of-the-class}
```

Please, in the future, consider adding a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of a screenshot.
Your request will be better received ;)